# After Sierra install, I can no longer scroll using trackpad. I must use down arrow

Tags: trackpad, macos

Post Sierra install, I can's scroll using track pad. I also can't backup using time machine nor external drive connected by USB

Answer (score 1):

What's the fix for this on the MacBook Pro after updating to Sierra as well however I create a new user account and scrolling functions well w/ the trackpad built in....that's really odd as this issue is specific to upgrading to scrolling and only to my user account that was upgraded.  The root user and other users created are ok.